# Сайт не доступен по адресу HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https

Купил сертификат SSl. Установил и настроил на сервере Nginx ключи и сертификат.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/avtosmoke.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/7934558.key;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    server_name avtosmoke.ru www.avtosmoke.ru;
}
```

Но сайт по прежнему не доступен по `https`.

Через внешние сервисы проверял - пишет что на сайте установлен SSl сертификат корректно.

Должно пройти время или `https` на сайте сразу должен работать?

Comment: сразу должен. покажи конфиг nginx

Comment: Что значит не доступен? Больше подробностей, пожалуйста

Comment: server {
 listen 443;
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/avtosmoke.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/7934558.key;
 ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
 server_name avtosmoke.ru www.avtosmoke.ru;
 }

Comment: вполне себе работает. только вы не указали программе nginx (с помощью [директивы root](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#root)), где искать index.html

Comment: Сайт по протоколу https не доступен

Comment: это все что в конфиге?? или чисто часть с https?

Comment: имеет смысл закрыть этот вопрос как дубликат (заданного позже, но более развёрнутого) вопроса от того же автора: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/900816/178576

Answer (score 1):

У тебя ssl настроен, вот, смотри:

```
$ curl --verbose 'https://www.avtosmoke.ru'
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.avtosmoke.ru/
*   Trying 80.87.203.85...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.avtosmoke.ru (80.87.203.85) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=PositiveSSL; CN=www.avtosmoke.ru
*  start date: Oct 31 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 31 23:59:59 2019 GMT
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fa637805e00)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: www.avtosmoke.ru
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 404 
< server: nginx/1.14.0
< date: Wed, 31 Oct 2018 10:42:27 GMT
< content-type: text/html
< content-encoding: gzip
< 
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host www.avtosmoke.ru left intact
```

Проблема лишь в том, что не прописаны настройки отдачи контента, связи с бекендом и т.д.

Для простейшей проверки ты можешь дописать общий `location`:

```
server {
    server_name            avtosmoke.ru www.avtosmoke.ru;
    listen                 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/certs/avtosmoke.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private/7934558.key;

    location / {
        return 200 'Hello dude!';
    }
}
```