# Сайт не отдаёт контент по HTTPS

Tags: nginx, битрикс

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться,почему сайт доступен по https но не отдаёт контент ? Как настроить nginx на правильную работу ???

Вот содержимое nginx.conf

```
user bitrix;
worker_processes 8;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 10240;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections  10240;
}

http {

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name avtosmoke.ru;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/avtosmoke.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/7934558.key;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}



    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/force-download;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    # Description of supported access log formats
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local - $upstream_response_time] '
                  '$status "$request" $body_bytes_sent '
                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    log_format common '$remote_addr - - [$time_local - $upstream_response_time] '
                    '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $msec';

  log_format balancer '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_iso8601] "$host" '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "schema: $scheme" '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                    '"$request_length" : "$request_time" -> $upstream_response_time';

    log_format debug '$upstream_response_time,"$time_local","$remote_addr","$request",$status,$body_bytes_sent';


  # upload default maps
  include bx/maps/*.conf;

  # settings files
  include bx/settings/*.conf;

    # Disable request logging in nginx by default
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  common;
    access_log          off;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    client_max_body_size        1024m;
    client_body_buffer_size     4m;

    # Parameters for back-end request proxy
    proxy_connect_timeout       300;
    proxy_send_timeout      300;
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_buffer_size       64k;
    proxy_buffers           8 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size  10m;

    # Assign default error handlers
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    error_page 404 = /404.html;

    # Content compression parameters
    gzip                on;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_static         on;
    gzip_http_version       1.0;
    gzip_types          application/x-javascript application/javascript text/css;

    # add_header
    include bx/conf/http-add_header.conf;

    # Set default website
    include bx/site_enabled/*.conf;

    # Set additional websites
    include bx/site_ext_enabled/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: а как он должен отдавать контент?

Comment: судя по всему у вас BitrixVM если так, то вы настраиваете https вообще не в том конфиге. Конфиг для https подключения лежит в include bx/site_enabled/*.conf; Корневой конфиг трогать не стоит, а то можно уронить все

Comment: где находится папка include bx/site_enabled ?

Comment: как можно догадаться по содержимому приведённого файла, сильно покорёженному битриксо-специфичными настройками, секции server здесь вообще не должно быть. а должна она быть, возможно, в одном из файлов, подпадающих под маску `bx/site_enabled/*.conf` (относительно каталога, в котором находится приведённый файл). **уточняйте в документации, согласно которой этот файл покорёжен**

Comment: скорее всего, вам надо сделать дубликат одной из уже существующих секций server из файлов `bx/site_enabled/*.conf`, добавив/изменив там директивы listen и ssl*. // в общем, вы не туда впихнули секцию server, да ещё и фактически пустую, без огромного количества необходимых директив.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить команду `nginx -t` либо от имени администратора `sudo nginx -t`. Для начала это позволит увидить возможные ошибки в конфигурации nginx.

Если ошибок не найдёте, то почитайте [про настройку https на nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

Comment: Ошибок нет
Настроил по мануалу,ошибка 404

Comment: нужно немного больше информации: url куда отправляете запрос, а также секцию server + location к запрашиваемому url'у. Также советую убедиться, что вы запрашиваете именно https версию сайта (пользуйтесь в консоли curl -I <url>  это позволит посмотреть в чистом виде ответ сервера)